# How to do rolling upgrade with zero downtime

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible to do a job version update with zero downtime ?

Maybe with [HA configuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html) ? i.e replacing the standby job with the updated one, next cancel the master which will cause the `standby` (updated) to be the `master` and then upload a new updated job instead of the `master` we cancelled in the previous phase, in order to maintain HA. 
Is this scenario possible ? are there other scenarios that can achieve zero downtime on job version update ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Flink HA mode is actually appropriate for zero-downtime job upgrades. HA mode ensures that a failing Jobmanager can be replaced without losing state information, but isn't HA in the sense that "unavailability" still occurs between the time the primary Jobmanager fails and the secondary Jobmanager takes over. (Or in the case of systems like Kubernetes, when the lone Jobmanager fails a healthcheck and is replaced)

For some types of jobs, zero-downtime upgrades are possible but not supported by Flink itself. For example, if your job outputs to an Elasticsearch index, you could bring up the upgraded job from a savepoint in parallel with the original but writing to a new index, and when it has caught up, switching your clients (or Elasticsearch index alias) to reference the new index.

Another technique I've considered but never tried would be to build into your applications a way to configure a flag that says when to start or stop emitting data. That way, you could update the configuration of the original job to drop (not forward to a sink) any windowed data starting at some timestamp in the near future, then run the upgraded job and configure it to emit its first window at that time.

Built-in support for zero-downtime "handoffs" is a feature that would be pretty nice to have in Flink for many use-cases.